# Computer Does not turn on after Suspend or Hibernate

Tags: 16.04, suspend, lenovo, hibernate

I am trying to follow the official Ubuntu guide to enabling suspend and hibernate on my laptop computer.

The  guide starts by test with the command line with `sudo pm-hibernate` (it does not wake up) and then to modify a `.plka` file.  At the moment my file is identical to theirs.  This is 16.04 LTS.
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate$
ResultActive=yes
```

Previous attempts at modifying my ubuntu instance have even left some surprises turning on and off the computer with a long sequence of

```
[OK] message
[OK] message 
[OK] message
...
```

and I manually have to turn the computer off at the end. I had been hoping the issue would go away after upgrading to 16.04

The computer is a Lenovo B570 admittedly a few years old, should not be an issue.